# Is it possible to use global variable in backbone.js view?

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to use global variable in backbone.js view ?

exmpl:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

 counter: null ; // is this possible ?

 initialize: function(){ 

 this.render();

 },

 render: function(){



}


});
```

Comment: That would be an instance variable a particular view instance, not global to all instances of the view.

Comment: Aside from what @asawyer mentioned, that is invalid JavaScript syntax, it would need to be `counter: null,`

Comment: Thany you guy, yes I see it now (; is one off the problems), I am very new in OOP so I don't know all of terminology.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can easily store variables in at least 3 different scopes:

- Regular instance variables unique to each view instance

  - these can be stored as properties on the view's `this` object
  - Example: `this.selectedItem = this.$el.find('.selected');`
- Class-level variables shared by all instances of the view

  - these can be stored on the View class's constructor function
  - Example: `TodoView.counter = 0;` (put that after your entire `.extend` invocation)
- True global variables (yes, these are bad, but since you asked)

  - you can leak these by omitting `var` or just explicitly assign to the `window` object
  - Example: `window.appLaunchTime = new Date()`

Comment: Thany you very much (sorry for my english or for my javascript knowlege I am noob in both. )

Comment: window.xxx is not working in backbone.js. Any ideas?? (xxx is a variable name)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Peter already said, if you are interested in having what amounts to a private variable that is available across all instances of the `TodoView` you create then you could do something like the following.

```
(function () {
  var counter = 0; //This can be used now as a private variable inside TodoView

  window.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){ 
      this.render();
      counter += 1;
    },

    render: function(){
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in static scope

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
TodoView.counter++//reference it this way
},{
 counter: null ;})
```

may serve somewhat like a global variable