# object is possibly undefined error when trying to declare a variable in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, marionette, declare

I am using a backbone model:

```
export class test = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
     name : ''},
     x = 'test'
)}{

function(){
console.log(this.x)}
}
```

However I get an error on the console. log that says 'property x may not exist on type test'. Am I declaring global variables wrong in backbone? Im quite new to js

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do here with this code (it seems it has syntax errors), but if your purpose is defining global variables with Backbone.JS, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13647963/3780985) out.

Comment: @Ert I just want to be able to access variable x

Comment: Can you please check my answer below? Please let me know if it is not good for you, and why. If it solves your issue, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access x defined in the Backbone Model/View and access it from somewhere else, you can define it as an attribute like so: `x: null` or give any value. By the way, defining it is not mandatory.

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        x: 0,
    },
});

var myTestModel = new TestModel();

console.log(myTestModel.x);
```

This would print zero.

You can do the same with a view.

Does this answer your question?